# How to put HTML doument on WinRAR and email it

Tags: windows-7, html, winrar

I have prepared a HTML document and I have to mail to my sir's ID by 20 Jan 2014. I have to put the entire folder to WinRAR. The folder is about 427 KB. I already have WinRAR installed on my computer. I selected the entire folder and right clicked and pointed to **compress to "HTML.rar" and email**. Then I got the folder named HTML.rar. I opened it. The browser opened and the web page just loaded and loaded. It never opened. I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You have to do this with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you had a few files in a folder, compressed them with WinRAR and than emailed them.
Than you unpacked the rar file got the folder.
Opened the HTML document and opened it with your browser.
And it kept loading and loading.

Try to compress it again, there is no simple answer why your html file is corrupted.